# How to fill in blanks based off another column's values in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, data-manipulation

Here is the code and resulting dataframe

```
category <- c("East","BLANK","NorthEast","BLANK","BLANK")
subcat <- c("East","North","SW","NE","SE")
data1 <- as.data.frame(category)
data1$subcat <- subcat


**Category**  **Subcat**
East        East            
BLANK       North           
NorthEast   SW          
BLANK       NE          
BLANK       SE
```

The East category contains subcat East and North. The NorthEast category contains subcat SW,NE,SE.
As you can see there are blanks for each category. How would I make so the 2nd value in Category is East and 4th and 5th row is North East? I have many more rows in the actual data so a way to do this would be helpful.

The result should be

```
**Category**  **Subcat**
East           East         
*East*         North            
NorthEast      SW           
*NorthEast*    NE           
*NorthEast*    SE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could convert the 'BLANK' to `NA` and use `fill`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
data1 %>%
   na_if( "BLANK") %>%
   fill(category)
```

-output

```
    category subcat
1      East   East
2      East  North
3 NorthEast     SW
4 NorthEast     NE
5 NorthEast     SE
```

Comment: 10 sec. too late!:-)

Comment: This is perfect.. thank you. Will upvote when I can

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `dplyr` only solution:
First we group by every string that is not `BLANK`,
then replace all group members with first value:

```
data1 %>% 
  group_by(x = cumsum(category != "BLANK")) %>% 
  mutate(category = first(category)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-x)
```

```
 category  subcat
  <chr>     <chr> 
1 East      East  
2 East      North 
3 NorthEast SW    
4 NorthEast NE    
5 NorthEast SE
```